# GNU malloc_info(): get really allocated memory?

Tags: linux, memory-management, malloc

I'm trying to investigate memory use of a large multi-threaded server.  According to mallinfo(), I get `arena=350M` and `fordblks=290M`, which suggests most of the space is actually wasted inside `malloc()`.  The `malloc_info()` function gives a nice XML data structure that is supposed to be self-explanatory.  Still, can someone explain to me

- Is heap `0` special?  Is the that main arena in which all others reside?
- Are the `<size from=.../>` chunk allocated, free/available or both?
- What is the `<system>` element?  Memory allocated using `mmap()/sbrk()`?
- What is the `<aspace>` element?  Available memory?
- What about `<aspace type="mprotect" .../>`?

Just for a start, I'd like to be able to plot total memory allocated by the application, i.e., everything allocated and not yet freed, according to what `malloc()` thinks.

Comment: Going through the source, I figured out that one can compute the amount of freed and not yet reused memory (available) by summing all `total` fields of all `size` and `unordered` elements.  That answers my second point.

Comment: More source analysis: `<system type="current" size="Size"/>` is the same as the `mallinfo()` `arena` field.

Answer (score 1):

A large amount of virtual memory usage is not necessarily a problem.  The default malloc implementation will allocate large amounts of storage per thread in order to avoid contention issues.  This happens particularly on 64-bit implementations which are pretty common nowadays.  You should not worry unless you experience problems with the size of resident memory or you get paging problems.

[Kevin Grigorenko](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/kevgrig/entry/linux_native_memory_fragmentation_and_process_size_growth?lang=en) has written a number of blog posts which deal with memory usage in relation to WebSphere, but they are applicable to any large multi-threaded process.

Comment: Thanks.  I also found http://files.cnblogs.com/files/hseagle/demo.pdf, which helps a little understanding GNU malloc.